# Replace only a few headers in dataframe from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I want to change the last 30 headers of. I have a list of the values that need to be changed, but I want to keep the original first two headers from the dataframe. For example, my dataframe resembles

```
Customer ID     Email     Topwater    ...    Plastics    Finesse
12345           me@me.com 1           ...    1           0
...
```

and my list is:

```
[Bait #1, Bait #2, Bait #3, ... , Bait #10, Bait #11]
```

I'm looking achieve this:

```
Customer ID     Email     Bait#1    ...    Bait #10    Bait #11
12345           me@me.com 1         ...    1           0
...
```

I tried this (where df_binary is the dataframe with the headers I want to change, but it doesn't seem to do anything, just returns the initial dataframe:

```
header_list = ['Customer ID','Email']
header_list.extend(list_of_baits)
df_binary.iloc[:,2:37].columns = my_list2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think need for replace last 3 values - convert all columns names without last to `list` and add new items:

```
print (df)
   Customer         ID  Email Topwater  ...  Plastics  Finesse
0     12345  me@me.com      1      ...    1         0        4

list_of_baits = ['Bait #1','Bait #2','Bait #3']
#for last 30 change -3 to -30
df.columns = df.columns[:-3].tolist() + list_of_baits
print (df)
   Customer         ID  Email Topwater  Bait #1  Bait #2  Bait #3
0     12345  me@me.com      1      ...        1        0        4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the array underlying your dataframe columns and update the last *n* items:

```
list_of_baits = ['Bait #1', 'Bait #2', 'Bait #3']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Customer ID', 'Email', 1, 2, 3])

arr = df.columns.values
arr[-3:] = list_of_baits  # change -3 to -30
df.columns = arr

print(df.columns)

Index(['Customer ID', 'Email', 'Bait #1', 'Bait #2', 'Bait #3'], dtype='object')
```

Note you should not attempt to update `df.columns` directly, since Pandas index objects do not support mutable operations. Nor should you attempt to update `df.columns.values` directly, as this may have unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Data from jpp `rename`

```
df= df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns[-3:],list_of_baits)))
#df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns.values[-3:],list_of_baits)))
Out[238]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Customer ID, Email, Bait #1, Bait #2, Bait #3]
Index: []
```

Comment: What would happen with duplicate column names (probably bad practice, but good to know the impact)?

Comment: @jpp `duplicate column` I would say , if a dataframe contain duplicate column ,  structure is corrupt(at least not good), I did not consider this situation for sure , but do i need to consider it as well ?

Comment: @jpp duplicate columns can not using this one , typically, still dict base . :-)